# Add comma Separated Words in textbox and perform an function

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, electron

I have here my Program that takes an Word from #myTextarea0 and then gives an output to an other TextArea, Everything is working but What I want now is to add as many Words as I want Comma ',' Separated Word1,Word2,Word3 So it will take first Word run the code give output and then go to the next Word after comma when there are no words anymore stop the process. Any Idea how do do this? Here my JS Code & HTML:

```
const puppeteer = require("puppeteer");

    async function MyFunction() {
      const browser = await puppeteer.launch({
        headless: false,
        args: ["--disable-infobars"]
      });
      const page = await browser.newPage();

      var site = "https://www.website.com/";

      //From #myTextarea0 I get my Strings already separated by Comma
      var s = $("#myTextarea0").val();
      var split = s.split(",");
      //GoTo URL + String EXAMPLE: www.website.com/string from #myTextarea0 (Works already need only after first run take next and run again)
      await page.goto(site + split[1]);
      //Here above by adding [1] to split he takes one string from the #myTextarea0 but how to take one and jump to the next and test again?

      try {
        await page.waitForSelector(".XYZ");
        await page.$(".XYZ");

        $("#myTextarea").val(s);
        $("#btntest").text("Start Testing");

      } catch (e) {
        $("#myTextarea1").val(s);
        $("#btntest").text("Start Testing");

      } finally {
        browser.close();
        $("#btntest").text("Start Testing");
      }

      MyFunction();
    }

    MyFunction();
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

JS strings have a split method which converts them into arrays of strings by dividing them at each instance of specified argument:

```
var s = "First,Second,Third,Fourth";
var split = s.split(',');
console.log(split);//expected output: ["First", "Second", "Third", "Fourth"]
for (var i = 0; i < split.length; i++)
    doSomething(split[i]);
```

Comment: But how to call the textarea here the code how I tried it and got stuck 
     `//WordCounter
$(htag).on('keyup', function() {
  var count = $(htag).val().trim().split(',');
  $('#myTextarea0').text(count.length);
});`

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean "call the textarea"?

Comment: I'm not really sure if the `doSomething` in your Example only is a placeholder or it actually need to be like that, Or do I need do add this before the function

Comment: It's just a placeholder.

Answer (score 0):

```js
const textIn = document.querySelector("#in");
const textOut = document.querySelector("#out");
const btn = document.querySelector("button");

const addCommas = () => {
  const arr = textOut.value !== '' ? textOut.value.split(',') : [];
  arr.push(textIn.value);
  textOut.value = arr.join(",");
  textIn.value = '';
  
};

btn.addEventListener("click", addCommas);
```

```html
<label for="in">Type words here</label>
<input type="text" id="in"><br><br>
<label>Output</label>
<input type="text" id="out">
<br><br>
<button>Calc</button>
```

Comment: This looks like exactly what I'm seaching for, But now my `(async () => {` function needs to take the first `Word1,Word2` run the Code then take the next in this example `Word2` and run the code again. Any Examples for this?

Comment: I didn't understand exactly what you're trying to do. Do you want to run the `async` function for each word in the text?

Comment: Yes Exactly that is what I want, Can you help me out here with an Example?